# Is it possible to somehow inline a function in python? ( for both performance + maintainability )

Tags: python, python-2.7

### Is it possible to somehow inline a function in python?

I have a very long function in python, which I want to split up for readability in several functions. So the parts gets called only from one point, the in program, but very often.

This reduces performance since function calls are very expensive.

Is there a method to both maintain the unsplitted performance, while improving readability/maintainence?

Comment: "...function calls are very expensive." Have you measured this, that is, compared the long function and the one split in multiple parts?

Comment: Yes i profiled it and there is definitely a not so small slow down. The long function gets called very very often.

Comment: If you are so worried about performance, then consider using a compiled language like Cython or C for the most critical parts.

Comment: Could you be quantitative and state profiling overhead times?

Comment: If the time spent calling a function is a bottleneck, Python is not the right language for your use case.

Comment: I guess your question is too vague. Give us some more information such as performance gains and code

Comment: FWIW, when comparing performance you should look at percentages, not at absolute numbers (i.e. "50% slowdown" means something, "2 usec slowdown" doesn't mean anything). This might sound obvious, but it is a frequent mistake

Comment: Oh, and other than Cython there's also PyPy: 100% Python compatible, but with a just in time compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Python doesn't support inline functions.

Comment: Mark, you might want to know that your text does not prove to be correct & you might want to update or remove the original statement. **Anyway, PF-2016**

Comment: @user3666197 Python doesn't support it in the OP's definition, writing multiple Python functions but inlining them to have the same performance as a single function.  It isn't in the language definition.  Sure you can write an extension in *another* language that improves performance.  C++ has inlining; Python does not.

Comment: With all due respect, Mark, the **`numba`** use-case does hold both the OP's definition & OP's motivation (performance+maintainability+(cit.)"... very, very often" call/code re-use) while at the same time does provide purely pythonesque solution [*I would dare to accuse Travis for "not keeping (also OP's) python ideals"*]. Yes, there are limitation of what can be numba-accelerated, but that is why there are other approaches (just let's take the genuine **`PyInline`** worlds-of-c) mentioned. Yes, Guido had initially another mindset, but check Mitchell Charity's note in PyInline ref'd below.

Comment: @user366197, Your definition of inlining differs from mine.  Does Python have a language function similar to C++'s inline keyword? No.  Can you write extensions that accelerate performance? Yes.

Comment: In a serious context, Stroustrup himself in [The design and evolution of C++] refers to `inline` as being a 'hint' to the compiler. It allows to define the same function in more than one translation unit. This is a prerequisite for inlining the function at a call-spot (**without link-time optimization**), which is where the **keyword** got it's name. IMHO, OP is not related to keyword(s), nor to c/C++ language per se, nor to compile-/link-time code-optimisation, **but to root idea** of inline-d pieces of code ( i.e. **why to design a code in this particular way**, independently of keywords )

Answer (score 5):

### There are several ways to inline in Python

Besides **`numba`** and similar JIT compilers ( which retain their own inline caches ), that may help you in JIT-code-reuse, as you denoted in numerous re-call of the unspecified function,
there are several ways how to **inline** into Python code.

---

### Inline symbolic x86 `ASM` assembly language into `python`

```
from pyasm              import Program
from pyasm.data         import String
from pyasm.macro        import syscall
from pyasm.instructions import mov, ret, push, add
from pyasm.registers    import eax, ebx, ecx, edx, ebp
import sys

def example():
    msg = 'Hello World!'
    prog = Program(     # _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
                        #
                        ### ASSUME NOTHING - a lovely ASM note to always remember & self.remind
                        mov(ebx, 1),
                        mov(ecx, String(msg)),
                        mov(edx, len(msg)),
                        syscall('write'),
                        ret(),
                        # _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
                        )
    fun = prog.compile()
    fun()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example()
```

### Inline <sup>almost</sup>  **`c`** language into `python`

```
from pycca.cc import CCode, Function, Assign, Return

code = CCode( [ Function( 'int', 'add_one', [( 'int', 'x' )],
                        [
                          Assign( x='x + 1' ),
                          Return('x')
                          ])
                ])
print code.dump_asm()
print "3 + 1 = %d" % code.add_one( 3 )
```

[For **details & other options** look at >>> this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29153140/3666197)

---

### Inline **`c`** language into `python` <sup>( since 2001 )</sup>

```
import PyInline, __main__

m = PyInline.build( language     = "C",
                    targetmodule = __main__,
                    code         = """
                                   /*_______________________________WORLDS-OF-C*/


                                     double my_C_adder( double a, double b )
                                     {
                                                        return a + b;
                                     }


                                   /*_______________________________WORLDS-OF-C*/
                                  """
                    )

print my_C_adder( 4.5, 5.5 )                     # Should print out "10.0"
```

[**Another approach** at >>> PyInline](http://pyinline.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

CPython interpreter does not support function inlining.

For performance-critical sections you may consider writing C-extension or using [C Foreign Function Interface](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library.

> C Foreign Function Interface for Python. The goal is to provide a
>   convenient and reliable way to call compiled C code from Python using
>   interface declarations written in C.

Another alternative is [PyPy](http://pypy.org) interpreter, which is equipped with JIT compiler and tends to achieve [huge performance gains](http://speed.pypy.org).

> It depends greatly on the type of task being performed. The geometric
>   average of all benchmarks is 0.14 or 7.0 times faster than CPython